Revit api StairsEditScope example Problem
I want to try the example from https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/47e4576e-4b01-ed1f-6dc1-885b6780aa07.htm. I'll use my own method to find the bottomLevel and topLevel, and then input them into the example.
public class Test : IExternalCommand
{
    public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        try
        {
            var uidoc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument;
            var doc = uidoc.Document;
            var view = doc.ActiveView;
            Level levelBottom = LevelUtils.GetCurrentLevel(doc, view);
            Level levelTop = LevelUtils.FindUpperLevel(doc, levelBottom);
            

            CreateStairs(doc, levelBottom, levelTop);

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TaskDialog.Show("錯誤", $"{ex.Message}\n\n{ex.StackTrace}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}

However, the result turned out to be very strange. The height of the generated Stair far exceeds the topLevel height. Yet, in the Stair properties under "Constraints," the level bindings appear to be correct. I want to know if I missed something, as it didn't automatically calculate the height between bottomLevel and topLevel.

